# Nest - Elastic Search - Find case-insensitive substring, slashes allowed

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Say I've indexed a document in Elastic with these two `keyword` fields:

1. `"lastModified": "02/03/2020"`
2. `"theText": "Hello there"`

I want to support *case-insensitive substring* searches against both fields.

So that the doc is matched when I search `"lastModified"` with any of these for the `QueryString`:

- `"02"`
- `"2/03"`
- `"/0"`
- `"2020"`

*And* the doc should match when I search `"theText"` for any of these (note case changes):

- `"helLO"`
- `"lo there"`
- `"the"`

You get the idea. **I just need a simple case-insensitive substring search**. No fuzziness or anything fancy. I've tried wildcards, regexes, escaping the slashes for `"lastModified"`, remapping `/` to `_slash_`, and I am stuck. Wildcards work *except when there's a slash*. How can I get the wildcard approach to work with slashes? Or is there a better way?

### Edit

I'd prefer to avoid going the N-Gram route, since the text data could be a very long paragraph and it would create many grams :).

To summarize, my preferred solution would:

- Not require N-Grams (our text can be quite long)
- Be case-insensitive
- Support slashes in the input

For now I'm using an ugly Regex against a Keyword field. It works but feels pretty silly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) for a substring match. Since you want to keep `/` also, then, you need to add `punctuation` in the `token_chars` as well

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "lastModified": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "theText": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "theText": "Hello there"
}
{
  "lastModified": "02/03/2020"
}
```

**Search Query on field 1:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "theText": "helLO"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67825121",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.970927,
        "_source": {
          "theText": "Hello there"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query on field 2:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "lastModified": "2/03"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67825121",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.0497348,
        "_source": {
          "lastModified": "02/03/2020"
        }
      }
    ]
```

***Have tried other queries also, and they are showing the correct result as per your use case.***

---

**Update 1:**

Elasticsearch uses a standard analyzer if no analyzer is specified. Assuming that the `lastModified` and `theText` field is of `text` type, so "02/03/2020" will get tokenized into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "02",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "03",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "2020",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when you are doing a wildcard query on any of the above field, then it will search for the tokens shown above. Since there is no token that matches "2/03", you will be getting empty results for the query.

It is better to use a keyword field for wildcard queries. If you have not explicitly defined any index mapping then you need to add .keyword to both the fields. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the fields).

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "lastModified.keyword": {
        "value": "*2/03*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67825121",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "lastModified": "02/03/2020"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "theText.keyword": {
        "value": "*lo there*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67825121",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "theText": "Hello there"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm a bit nervous about the cost of N-gram in the case of a long string. We might be indexing a big paragraph of text. Is that nothing to worry about?

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol yes, ngrams are a bit costly as so many tokens are generated for the same string. But according to your use case, I could not figure out any other way to achieve all the cases

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol are the search results shown above same as what you expect to get ?

Comment: the thing is, wildcards work with the defaults unless there are slashes. Is there no way to have the wildcard behavior but also support slashes in the search text? Rather than go the N-Gram route just to allow '/' in a search term.

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: The wildcard version turned out to be case-sensitive. I ended up using an ugly Regex against a `Keyword` type to get this to work. It expands into `[Ss][Ee][Aa][Rr][Cc][Hh]` etc. It's ugly but at least it lets me case-insensitive search with special chars, and without exploding NGrams. Thank you for your help though, it drew my attention to needing the `Keyword` flag.